# Get TO and CC emails from Mail Composer in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c

My goal is i am sending email by using Mail composer in iPhone. Before sending email, need to validate and send to server those mail ids. Can you please guide me how to get those ids from iPhone mail composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mail composer makes use of the MFMailComposeViewController which is not open for read access nor does the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol reveal anything usable. I am sorry.